# how to stop images from rendering on setState

Tags: react-native

I have images associated with a counter and based on this increment or decrement in counter, a calculation is done and displayed in a text at the bottom.

The problem is that when I render, the images get rendered again and are loaded again and again and again. which I dont want.

If I dont render, the text will not update with the calculated amount.
For the counter I am using react-native-counter.

I have already tried with shouldcomponentupdate, but I want to stop only image rendering, the rest should work.

Please advise.

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header
                    backgroundColor="#25D366"
                    leftComponent={
                        <Icon
                            name="menu"
                            size={40}
                            color={"#fff000"}
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
                        />
                    }
                    centerComponent={{
                        text: "Veg & Fruits",
                        style: {
                            color: "#ffffff",
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: "bold",
                        },
                    }}
                    rightComponent={<Icon name="home" color={"#ff0000"} />}
                ></Header>
                /// this is searchbar component,
                <SearchBar
                    fontColor="#ffffff"
                    fontWeight="bold"
                    fontSize={20}
                    iconColor="#c6c6c6"
                    shadowColor="#ffffff"
                    cancelIconColor="#c6c6c6"
                    backgroundColor="#25D366"
                    placeholder="Search here"
                    onChangeText={(text) => {
                        this.setState({ photos: [] });
                        this.state.search = text;
                        this.filterList(this.state.search);
                        console.log("text changed");
                    }}
                    onPressCancel={(text) => {
                        text = "";
                        //this.filterList(text);
                    }}
                    onPress={(text) => {
                        console.log("rendering");
                        console.log("now text is: ", this.state.search);
                    }}
                />
                /// in this view images are displayed using functions
                <View>
                    <ScrollView
                        style={{
                            height: Dimensions.get("window").height - 200,
                        }}
                    >
                        <View
                            key={Date.now()}
                            style={{
                                flex: 1,
                                flexDirection: "column",
                                flexWrap: "wrap",
                            }}
                        >
                            {this.filterList(this.state.search)}
                            {this._renderImages()}
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>

                    <CalcText tt={total_num} />
                </View>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class CalcText extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ta: 0,
        };
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        console.log(nextProps.tt);
        if (this.props.tt !== nextProps.tt) {
            console.log("changed");
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("Not changed");
            return false;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ height: 40, backgroundcolor: "ff0000" }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 26, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                    Total : {this.props.tt}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show code so that we can help you. Is the problem that you want to prevent a image double render or you have infinit rendering?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `TextBox` component and split it from `ImageComponent`. In this way the images will not be bound to the state of the component rendering text, and you can safely change `TextBox` state and text preventing `ImageComponent` to re-render.

***Edit:***

Okei, now i get it. I think you have no possibility to do it like this.

Let's formalize the problem:

```
<Parent>
    <Images calc={functionToCalc} />
    <CalcText totalAmount={this.state.totalAmount}/>
</Parent>
```

`functionToCalc` is defined in in `<Parent>` and update parent state, something like:

```
const funcToCalc = () => {
   // when condition occurs
   this.setState({
      totalAmount : computedAmount
   })
}
```

The state of `<Parent>` has:

```
this.state : {
    totalAmount: none
}
```

Whenever condition (buttonClick?) occurs in `<Images/>` you run `functionToCalc` update `<Parent>` state and rerender `<CalcText>`. Problem here is that also `<Images>` will be rerender again as all the parent component will be rerender.

this is one of the way to pass info from siblings in React.

You only have a possibility if you want to prevent `<Images>` rerendering.

1. [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) or similar libraries for centralize state

You will move the computed calculation in a `Store` and `<CalcText/>` will read that from there. `<Images/>` component will trigger an action modifying that state but won't listen to that so not being rerender.

Comment: by TextBox you mean my own custom component or TextInput component

Comment: Please show the code so that we can help you, and let me share a possible solution !

Comment: so what happens is that i created a new component CalcText..  this component should render when counter is changed and the images should not render.